# How to sum a set of items in a list that all share a specific property?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of objects. Each object has a set of variables/properties. These consist of multiple decimal amounts and a string representation of a state. How would I sum each amount in the list of objects that has the same state?

I know I can do `Model.ReportList.Sum(x => x.Amount)` to get the sum of all Amount variables across the whole list. I want to do the same thing but only sum the `Amount` variables of each `x` that all have, for example, `x.State = "GA"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` *may* be a good answer, but **it's overkill if you only care about summing amounts for one state**. If that's what you need (as your question suggests), use `Where` extension instead:

```
Model.ReportList.Where(x => x.State == "GA").Sum(x => x.Amount);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking to group the values, which can be done using `GroupBy`, and then sum each group:

```
Model.ReportList.GroupBy(report => report.State, 
    (State, reports) => new { State, Sum = reports.Sum(report => report.Amount) });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sums = Model.ReportList.GroupBy(r => r.State)
   .Select(grp => new { State = grp.Key, Sum = grp.Sum(r => r.Amount) })
```